# Convert date field methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have variable "start" in my table with type `date`

So it is stored like "2015-01-01"

I want to print it only with month and year, and month in letter not number.
like "Jan 2015".

I can do `start.to_formatted_s(:long)` and `start.strftime('%m,%Y')`

But I can't combine those method. How do I do to combine those method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively try this:

```
start.strftime("%b %Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your [own format](http://apidock.com/rails/Date/to_formatted_s) like :

```
# config/initializers/date_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = '%b %Y'
```

and then use

```
start.to_formatted_s(:month_and_year)
```